# Rotating element on canvas object, relative to parent

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a pair of skis (two rectangles) on a skier (a square) at varying rotations. I don't quite understand how you line up rotated elements on a canvas as you rotate the *whole* canvas, not just the object.

At the moment I have this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

ctx.fillStyle = skiier.color;
ctx.fillRect(skiier.x, skiier.y, skiier.width, skiier.height);
ctx.fillStyle = '#00f';

var angle = 20;
ctx.rotate(angle*Math.PI/180);
ctx.fillRect(skiier.x, skiier.y,100,10);
ctx.fillRect(skiier.x, skiier.y + 20,100,10);
ctx.rotate(-angle*Math.PI/180);
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

But what I'd like to do is the following:

[image]

Bearing in mind the x and y coords of the skier is constantly changing, how can I adjust and position the skis relative to him?

I have a demo here if it helps:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/cfa7052ed205b664b066450910c830c5?editors=001

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the context `save`, `restore` and `translate` as follows:

```
// ...
var angle = 20;
ctx.save(); // save the state of the ctx
ctx.translate(skiier.x, skiier.y); // translate your context point to be the same as skiier.
ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillRect(-25, 0, 100, 10); // You can draw from new context point.
ctx.fillRect(-25, 20, 100, 10); // Same here.
// Instead of rotating back, use restore()...
// Useful to restore all ctx options as they were before the save()
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

To rotate around a point: you need to translate context to the point, rotate context, translate context back.

For example...

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

ctx.fillStyle = skiier.color;
ctx.fillRect(skiier.x, skiier.y, skiier.width, skiier.height);
ctx.fillStyle = '#00f';

var angle = 20;
ctx.translate(skiier.x, skiier.y);
ctx.rotate(angle*Math.PI/180);
ctx.translate(-skiier.x, -skiier.y);
ctx.fillRect(skiier.x, skiier.y,100,10);
ctx.fillRect(skiier.x, skiier.y + 20,100,10);
ctx.rotate(-angle*Math.PI/180);
```